Hp Victus 15 - Kworker ACPI issues
I have a HP Victus with AMD 8645HS and Nvidia 4050 and on installing Ubuntu 24 LTS I experience a kworker issues with lot of ACPI interrupts in D state with one CPU core always at 100% and even if I go to previous version or next version of kernel it doesn't help and the system load is in 80's. Any help is appreciated as I need Ubuntu for my deeplearning tasks

Bug track for exact issue
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=219055
https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/2073538
The workaround mentioned in the above at least before kernel v13 comes out is to blacklist ucsi_acpi module
PS: I have the exact same laptop model and i fixed the issue using the above steps
